# How put color in all math mode?

Tags: math-mode, color

I want to put all math mode in a color, for example, red. But I don't know how to do that. In this web I found how to do it, but in Beamer, I want do it too in Article, Book, etc.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `\everymath{\color{red}}`, `\everydisplay{\color{red}}`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure why you'd want such a device.

Comment: Sort of related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335/86

Answer (score 8):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\displaymath}{\color{red}\[}
\renewcommand{\enddisplaymath}{\]\@ignoretrue\color{black}}

\renewcommand{\(}{\relax\ifmmode\@badmath\else\color{blue}$\fi}
\renewcommand{\)}{\relax\ifmmode\ifinner$\color{black}\else\@badmath\fi\else \@badmath\fi}

\catcode`\$=13
\def${\ifmmode\)\else\(\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Una funzione $f:U \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}, U\){} aperto di $\mathbb{C}${} si dice  \textbf{olomorfa} se \`{e} \(\mathbb{C}\)-derivabile in ogni punto di \(U\), ovvero se \(\forall\) \(z_0 \in U\ \exists\){} finito
\begin{displaymath}
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_0}, h\in \mathbb{C}.
\end{displaymath}
\(f\){} \textbf{intera} se olomorfa su \(U=\mathbb{C}\).

\end{document}
```

However this solution is a little impractical for inline `math mode`. I suggest to use this trick only for `display math mode`, and use a contracted extra command when inline. Doing this with `\everymath` and `\everydisplay` is unsafe, as mentioned here: [`\everymath` and author color](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100263/everymath-and-author-color)

Comment: You can use the xspace package and then use \def${\ifmmode\)\xspace\else\(\fi} instead of \def${\ifmmode\)\else\(\fi}. With this we avoid using {} to add spaces