# Change inline equation point size in tcolorbox

Tags: equations, tcolorbox

We are trying to change inline and display equation font size as 10pt,
its worked for display equations not worked inline math, please advice, how to change
inline math equations point size?[image]

Please find MWE file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newenvironment{boxtype1}
{%
\everymath{\fontsize{12bp}{14bp}\selectfont}
\everydisplay{\fontsize{12bp}{14bp}\selectfont}
\begin{tcolorbox}[fontupper=\fontsize{10bp}{12bp}\selectfont\sffamily]}
{\end{tcolorbox}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{boxtype1}
Working capital management deals with the management of current assets — cash, accounts receivable and inventory — and their financing. Good working capital management is always important for companies.
$\alpha+\beta$ and ${1+0.05}$

\begin{align}\frac{\$ 20\, 000}{1+0.05} and {1+0.05}\end{align}
\end{boxtype1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, as always, provide MWE, which generate your image.

Comment: As expected: you define that all math environments had to use font size 12bp . Remove code line `\everymath{\fontsize{12bp}{14bp}\selectfont}` from preamble and  font size of in-line math will be the same as it is text.

Comment: Yes, my request increase inline math point size differ from text.

Comment: How to increase point size in the highlighted portions(inline math), we updated as 12pt but output shows as 10pt only?

Comment: (i) from a typography standpoint, using bigger letters for math than for other tex is a very poor choice, (ii) if you persist doing this, try `{\huge$\alpha+\beta$ and ${1+0.05}$}` (instead `\huge` you can use other font size), note: `\everymath` is not LaTeX comand, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100263/everymath-and-author-color

Comment: Thank you Zarko, spending time to us. Point (i): We just send sample MWE file to your reference, in my case box body text as 8pt Helvectica  and math font size 10pt times Point (ii) {\huge $...$} grouping worked, but we have thousands of inline math in my document, we need to control macros itself instead to replace each and every inline math.

Comment: Let me repeat again, using bigger font for in-line math than for other text is a very poor choice. I would not do this.