# \everymath and \everydisplay changes color of tables?

Tags: math-mode, color

I am trying to colorize equations (especially inline ones) so that they standout from the rest of the text and thus have used the `\everymath{}` and `\everydisplay{}` commands, however that also seems to affect tables.  Text is not affected though. Any idea why this happening or how to get around it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\everymath{\color{teal}}
\everydisplay{\color{magenta}}

\begin{document}

Some text.
Some text.
Some text.
Some text.
$x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}$
Some text.
Some text.
Some text.
Some text.
\[
  x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}
\]

\begin{table}[!h] % also colored?
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline
    Animal  &   Legs \\
    \hline
    Dogs    &   4 \\
    Human   &   1 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have discovered that `tabular` uses math mode.

Comment: math is used in lots of non-mathematical use, for tables it is used to get vertical centering which is the default alignment

Comment: As suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100263/everymath-and-author-color, adding `\makeatletter  \def\m@th{\mathsurround\z@\color{black}} \makeatother` should do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\everymath{\color{teal}}
\everydisplay{\color{magenta}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\def\m@th{\mathsurround\z@\color{black}}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

Some text.
Some text.
Some text.
Some text.
$x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}$
Some text.
Some text.
Some text.
Some text.
\[
  x=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}
\]

\begin{table}[!h] % also colored?
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline
    Animal  &   Legs \\
    \hline
    Dogs    &   4 \\
    Human   &   1 \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I followed the link and if I understand correctly, this workaround works under the assumption that environments like `tabular` or whatever that use math mode actually use the `\m@th` command? If this is not true is there any package that allows styling of all mathematics throughout the document in isolation safely?

Comment: @FirstUser, sorry that I am not aware of such a package..

Comment: This solution is risky. For example, it also changes the color of the \substack command. It may be safer to write a new command that does:
\everymath{\color{black}}
\begin{tabular}
...
\end{tabular}
\everymath{\color{teal}}